# How to avoid "Content Security Policy: The settings of the page blocked the loading of a resource inline ("default-src")"?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic4, content-security-policy, build-error

i am developing an Ionic 4 App. But suddenly after starting the app with `ionic serve --devapp` i just got the error the text `Cannot GET /` on my page.
I have no idea what i did to make this error appear. Earlier i ran the command `ionic cordova resources` but i don't think that the error is related to the command...
I also get the error

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/es7/reflect'

in my Terminal, but i don't know if this error coheres with the error above.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ionic run`, or set up a proxy, to avoid CORS issues.

Ionic posted [a blog article](https://blog.ionicframework.com/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/) about this, which would be useful if you need to use `ionic serve` for some reason. You almost certainly don't, however.